# How do I import another python file from folder to another folder

Tags: python, python-module

I have here  a python folder:
Inside is another 2 folders namely: session_9 and session_10
Here's what it looks like :
python

- session_9

  1. main.py
- session_10

  1. file1.py

I just want to import file1.py to my session_9 folder so that I can use it in my main.py file.
THANK YOU IN ADVANCE..

I'd try :

- from session_10.file1.py import sampfunc as sp # sampfunc is a samplefunction inside file1.py
- import sys
  sys.path.insert('D:\pythonfiles\python_session\python_session\session_10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python adds the parent folder of the main script that you are running to the PYTHONPATH / sys.path, so only the modules or packages declared under the `session_9` directory will be discoverable by default.

First, declare that session_10 is a package by creating an empty file named `__init__.py`

Then update the PYTHONPATH / sys.path to indicate where the package is located.

You can do this in the first two lines of the main.py script with sys.path.

```
import sys 
sys.path.insert(0, 'D:\pythonfiles\python_session\python_session')
```

Then you should be able to import the module with the following statement:

`from session_10.file1 import sampfunc`

Comment: It's working now.  Many thanks to your help Jorge. I'm struggling with this for an hour

Comment: Hmm... adding an `__init__.py` files makes the directory a *package*. In Python wordings a module is a single py file.

Comment: @SergeBallesta yes . that's why my code also didn't work. adding the __init.py__ makes it work.

Comment: You are right, i incorrectly name every package and subpackage a module because in vscode when you hover over the docstring of any of the `__init__.py ` files (`from  package.subpack.module import func`) it says that it is a module 

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in python:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(0, 'pythonfiles\python_session\python_session\session_10')
from file1 import #whatever function you have in file1.py
```